# Find the exact match of string on postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a query -

```
select whereto, id from table where id=1;
```

I need to find  the position of  `where` in this query. It should not consider the  column `whereto`.

How we can achieve it in postgres?

Comment: what do you mean by position of `where` ? Position as in where in the query `where` appears ?

Comment: ravi kumarr--
declare @var varhchar(100);


set @var='select whereto, id from table where id=1; '

select strpos(@var,'where') gives me 8. 
i need the position of  the 'where' and not of 'whereto'

Comment: did you try - `select strpos(@var,'where ')` with a space after `where`? Is there option to try regex?

Comment: ya do u know which regex to use to find it

Comment: what interface you're trying? what is the version of postgres?

Comment: i am using  postgress 11.11

Answer (score 0):

I could try this on psql on Mac Big Sur.

```
postgres=# \set myvar 'select whereto, id from table where id=1;';
```

And if I try `where`  (with a space), it gives me -

```
postgres=# select strpos(:'myvar','where ');
 strpos
--------
     31
(1 row)
```

As per the documentation, strpos takes only string and not regex. - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html